# Не понимаю, в чем проблема?

Tags: javascript

Есть задача: нужно вызвать функцию sumTo с аргументом n. n - это сколько раз нужно добавить к i единицу. Почему мне возвращает 101? т.е. почему прибавляется только один раз если есть for? пробовал и while, видимо тут не в цикле проблема.

```js
function sumTo(n) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    i = i + 1;
  }
  return i;
}
console.log(sumTo(100));
```

Comment: по условию остановки цикла. Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос ожидаемый результат.

Comment: а какой результат вы ожидаете? если к 1 сто раз прибавить 1, то получиться 101.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в цикле.

Переменная `i` является счетчиком цикла. На каждой итерации проверяется значение этой переменной и если оно больше параметра `n` происходит выход из цикла.

Таким образом при вызове `sumTo(100)` как только значение суммы становится больше 100, в данном случае 101 - происходит выход из цикла и возврат значение переменной.

Если нужно просуммировать числа от 1 до n, то результат лучше хранить в отдельной переменной:

```js
function sumTo(n) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum = sum + i;
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(sumTo(100));
```

Comment: А ещё лучше считать по формуле, а не так.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, если только речь идет о простой сумме, а не о выполнении какого-то действия еще